# How to pass the draft option for pdfpages to \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, pdfpages, package-options

If I use

```
\usepackage[draft]{pdfpages}
```

and include

```
\includepdf[...]{...}
```

everything works fine, i.e. instead of the included pages I get empty boxes. 
But if I use

```
\includegraphics[...]{...}
```

the actual picture is included. 
I cannot separately load "`graphicx`" because it is already loaded by "`pdfpages`".

How can I pass the draft option to `\includegraphics`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\PassOptionsToPackage`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfpages}
```

or you can use `draft` as a class option

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and it will be picked by `pdfpages` and `graphicx`. Another option would be to load `graphicx` *before* `pdfpages`, so you can use the desired option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfpages}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphics} % or \usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfpages}
```

LaTeX does not load packages more than once. Loading the package `graphics` the first time, enables `draft` mode. Package `pdfpages` loads `graphicx` and `graphicx` loads `graphics` without options each, thus LaTeX will not complain. The important thing is that the superset of all options specified in all load requests must be present at the first loading of the package.

Other alternatives are given in Gonzalo Medina's answer:

- Global option `draft` is seen by packages `graphics` and `graphicx`.
- Calling `\PassOptionsToPackage` *before* the first loading of `graphics` or `graphicx`.

### Key value setting

And yet another way is possible:

```
\usepackage[draft]{pdfpages}
\setkeys{Gin}{draft}
```

Package `graphicx` adds a key value interface for some of the options. `draft` can be set and unset later:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{draft}
... \includegraphics{...} ...
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
... \includegraphics{...} ...
```

Or the option can be set explicitly in `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[draft=false]{...}
```

However `final` is not defined this way. This option can only be used as package option.